# Data structure inside Executors

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, executors

We can provide a BlockingQueue implementations while defining ThreadPoolExecutors. However, if I use the factory (Executors) to create a single thread pool as shown below, I would like to know which blocking queue is used. I am guessing it is a LinkedBlockingQueue. The documentation talks about unbounded queue, but it does not reveal the implementation.

```
ExectorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Comment: The source is availble in src.zip, you can look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from Executors src:

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```